# Redirecting to a page in react-redux-router from an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a common action which fetches data from server. I am calling the action from various components. I want to redirect, if response code is `x`:

```
export  function commonApiCall(callUrl,data,reducer,method)
  {

    return dispatch =>
    {

      .....
      ....
      axios({
      method: callMethod,
      url: ,
      data: '',
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then( (response) => {
        if ( response.code == 'x'){
          // redirect I want to redirect here.
        }
        dispatch({
          type: reducer,
        });
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.warn('Actions - fetchJobs - recreived error: ', error)
      })
    }
  }
```

One solution is to add check in each and every component.But, I want a centralized solution.

Comment: I think `push` is what you are looking for, right? https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `import {push} from 'react-router-redux'` and dispatch the push event on the basis of response code check.

Comment: For the same, I need history. How will I get that in a action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `browserhistory.push('/sub-url')` which pushes the page route to your destiny route

Comment: I am using react-router v4, where browserhistory is not available.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux 
view this link and find the tutorial section and there you should use the react router too which solves your problem

Comment: are you using react Router in your app ?? if not so please install react router which is essential

Comment: I can't use browserhistory in react-redux.